# For an Azure Webapp, GET request from another website result in 403 error

Tags: azure, get, cors, azure-web-app-service

I have an issue with a Web App I run on Azure.

Said app is collection of GET endpoints witch return data.

If I try to run a GET request on my WebApp directly through browser everything run fine but if the same request is run from another website then it result in a 403 Forbidden error.

This is a problem because one case include my WebApp being a redirect address from another website.

- I tried allowing all CORS in Azure (a single '*' entry line).
- My 'Public network access' is 'Enabled with no access restrictions'

I have no control on the external website calling my azure app, in some specific scenarios it will directly redirect to my azure webapp resulting in GET request example 1, which works. In other scenarios it will call a similar GET request but with itself as a 'Referer', and this will fail (GET request example 2).

The same procedure work every-time and without issue in both cases when I run my WebApp on localhost, letting me think than the issue is on my Azure WebApp's parameters.

GET request example 1, this work on my webapp:

```
GET /oauth/token?someparam=somevalue HTTP/1.1
Host: wa-my-azure-website.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

GET request example 2, this is the failing request, featuring a "Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site" and a "Referer" website:

```
GET /oauth/token?someparam=somevalue HTTP/1.1
Host: wa-my-azure-website.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://oauth.theotherwebsite.net/
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

Error result :

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Tue, 05 Dec 2023 19:27:32 GMT
Server: thin
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Details on my azure webapp :

- Plan Type is App Service plan Basic (B1) on 1 instance
- Always on is set to true (stay awake)
- Operating System is Linux
- Publishing model is Container (Docker Hub)

EDIT:

- Added some detail on my current Azure webapp parameters and removed some bloated description.
- I did not include code of my GET request (written in Ruby-Sinatra, and dockerized) because it seems to never be reached anyway, even returning on first line or provoking a crash on first line change nothing.
- Websites name are censored because I don't know if true URL to external site are allow on StackOverflow.

Thanks everyone for reading and I hope someone has some insight for me.

Quentin

Comment: Can you specify which Application you are using and provide some code for better understanding.

Comment: @SureshChikkam thanks for the reply !
I edited the original post to remove bloat, added more info on the azure webapp settings, and hopefully provided a cleaner presentation of the problem.

As for the code, I don't think this is related, for example this minimal case : 
``` Ruby/Sinatra \n
get '/oauth/token' do \n
end \n
```
Should result in blank page, but a 403 is returned instead, letting me think than the issue is the code is not even reached.